# How do I upload files in docx and doc format?

Tags: nodes

I have added my code below which is used to upload a resume in CSV format, but now the requirement changed, and it is required I add the resumes in all formats (docx and doc).
I have tried adding  '#file_validate_extensions' => array('csv,docx'), but that gives me an error *Incorrect string value for title*. What are the modifications that should be done in the code to upload the resumes in all formats?

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\custom_migration\Form\UploadForm.
 */

namespace Drupal\custom_migration\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormState;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

class CsvUploadForm extends FormBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'csv_upload_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $file_size = t('Maximum file size: %size MB.', array('size' => file_upload_max_size()));
    $form['file_upload'] = array( 
      '#type' => 'file', 
      '#title' => t('File'), 
      '#size' => 40, 
      '#description' => t('Select the CSV file to be imported. ') . $file_size
    ); 
    $form['submit'] = array( '#type' => 'submit', '#value' => t('Save'), ); 
    // set the form encoding type 
    // $form['#attributes']['enctype'] = "multipart/form-data"; 
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $destination='public://csv';
    if (!file_exists($destination)) {
      mkdir($destination, 0777, true);
    }
    $validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array('csv'));
    $file = file_save_upload('file_upload', $validators, $destination, $replace = FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
    // check file uploaded OK 
    if (!$file) { 
      $form_state->setErrorByName('file_upload', t('A file must be uploaded'));
    } 
    else { 
      // set files to form_state, to process when form is submitted 
      $form_state->setValue('file_upload', array($file));
    } 
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // drupal_set_message($this->t('@can_name ,Your application is being submitted!', array('@can_name' => $form_state->getValue('candidate_name'))));
    /* Fetch the array of the  file stored temporarily in database */
    $line_max = \Drupal::state()->get('user_import_line_max', 1000);
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
    $filepath = ($form_state->getValue('file_upload')[0]->getFileUri());
    $handle = @fopen($filepath, "r");
    $job_id=\Drupal::request()->query->get('job_id');
    $row = 1;
    if ($handle !== FALSE) {
      while (($data = str_fgetcsv($handle, $line_max, ','))!==FALSE) {
        if ($row == 1) {
          $row++;
          continue;
        }
        $node = Node::create(array(
          'type' => 'job_application',
          'title' => $data[1],
          'langcode' => 'en',
          'uid' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
          'status' => 1,
          'field_fields' => array(),
        ));
        $node->field_email= $data[2];
        $node->field_notice_period = $data[5];
        $node->field_phone_number = $data[6];
        $node->field_i_agree_terms_and_conditio=1;
        $node->field_job_list=$job_id;
        $node->field_resume_status=$this->getTidByName('Applied');
        $location_vocabulary = 'location';
        $tid_l1 = $this->getTidByName($data[3]);
        if (!empty($data[3]) && $tid_l1 === 0) {
          $term = $this->createNewTerm($data[3],$location_vocabulary);
          $node->field_current_location = $term;
        }
        else{
          $node->field_current_location=$this->getTidByName($data[3]);
        }
        $tid_l2 = $this->getTidByName($data[4]);
        if (!empty($data[4]) && $tid_l2 === 0) {
          $term = $this->createNewTerm($data[4],$location_vocabulary);
          $node->field_preferred_location = $term;
        }
        else {
          $node->field_preferred_location = $this->getTidByName($data[3]);
        }
        $field_values = array(
          'uri' => file_create_url('sites/default/files/'.$data[7]),
          'uid' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
          'status' => 0,
        );
        $file = File::create($field_values);
        $file->save();
        $node->field_resume->setValue([
          'target_id' => $file->id(),
        ]);
        $skills_vocabulary = 'skill_sets';
        $skills = $data[8];                                                                                                      
        $node->field_applicant_skills = $skills;
        $node->save();
        $row++;
      }
      fclose($handle);
    }
    drupal_set_message($this->t('You have sucessfully uploaded resumes.'));       
    $form_state->setRedirect('view.review_requirements.review_jobs_page');
  }  

  /**
   * Utility: find term by name and vid.
   * @param null $name
   *  Term name
   * @param null $vid
   *  Term vid
   * @return int
   *  Term id or 0 if none.
   */
  public function getTidByName($name = NULL, $vid = NULL) {
    $properties = [];
    if (!empty($name)) {
      $properties['name'] = $name;
    }
    if (!empty($vid)) {
      $properties['vid'] = $vid;
    }
    $terms = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadByProperties($properties);
    $term = reset($terms);
    return !empty($term) ? $term->id() : 0;
  }

  public function createNewTerm($value, $categories_vocabulary) {
    $term = Term::create(array(
      'parent' => array(),
      'name' => $value,
      'vid' => $categories_vocabulary,
    ))->save();
    return $term;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to replace the file types in the following line.

```
$validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array('csv'));
```

Change it to this.

```
$validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array('docx','doc'));
```

Also, in `submitForm()` you are parsing the CSV file using `str_fgetcsv()` and importing the data in a node. So you have to find another way parsing your new data and creating this node.